# Custom Active Directory export

Tags: powershell, csv

I have been working on a custom script to leverage a bulk export of specific active directory data for 1.5k servers. The data i am looking for is Name, AD description and one AD Group with a specific pattern in its name (G_SCCM). After a few days of testing out various methods to achieve this i was able to come up with this script.

```
$computers = Get-Content 'path.txt' 
foreach ($computer in $computers)
 
{get-adcomputer -Identity $computer -Properties * | Select-Object name, description |
Export-Csv -path 'path' -append
}
```

I need to export data from AD for a list of servers. For each server, I need its Name, Description, and MemberOF properties. The group membership I'm interested in should start with G_SCCM. We have over 30 maintenance groups for patching, so it's not feasible to look individually in each group for its members. I tried using the MemberOF property, but it returns a blank statement every time. If the computer object is not a member of any groups that start with G_SCCM, highlight or leave the cell blank upon export.

Comment: what do you mean by "and one specific AD Group (G_SCCM)" are you saying that each computer object is a member of a group that contains "G_SCCM" in their name?

Comment: Are you looking for computers that are a direct member of that group, or might they be nested members? For example ServerA is a member of ProdSQLServers, and ProdSQLServers is a member of G_SCCM, making ServerA a nested member. If the servers will be direct members then Olaf's comment should make this pretty straight forward. Side note, you can pipe computer names to `Get-ADComputer`, so `$computers | get-adcomputer -prop memberof,description | select name,description,memberof | export-csv 'c:\path\to\file.csv' -notype` could go a long way

Comment: @Olaf gotcha I made the edits I appreciate the feedback. when I specify the MemberOf is coming out blank.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I need to pull from that list all of the computers that are part of that specific AD group.

Comment: so, from the file `path.txt` you need to exclude all computers that are NOT a member of `G_SCCM` ?

Comment: @Olaf I guess I forgot to specify that we have over 30+ groups starting with G_SCCM. so its easier fo me to define the search this way.

Comment: Indeed, what Olaf said, your question as you can see is causing a lot of comments meaning that your question is unclear. Please re-read your question and clarify.

Comment: i apologize for the confusion i will re-edit my question in a few.

Comment: I tried my suggested code above and it's no good. `MemberOf` comes out as "PropertyList" or some such garbage. You'd have to do `...| select Name,Description,@{l='Groups';e={$_.MemberOf -join '; '}} |...` to make it a string.  The piping bit is still valid though, so you can't constantly opening and closing the file to append to it.

Comment: Where are you getting error message? "Error message unable to compile"

Comment: let me know if that works with the edits I'm having a hard time thinking It might be time for me to take a break on this sorry

Comment: if is starts with G_SCCM it works with me @Olaf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're looking for the groupmembership for multiple groups I'd collect these groups first to be able to use them to compare the list of memberships a server has against.

```
$ServerList = Get-Content -Path 'path.txt'
$GroupList = Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -like '*G_SCCM*'" -SearchBase 'OU=Groups,DC=Contoso,DC=de'
$LookUpTable = $GroupList | 
    Select-Object -Property DistinguishedName, sAMAccountName | 
        Group-Object -AsHashTable -Property DistinguishedName

$Result = 
foreach ($ComputerName in $ServerList) {
    $ADComputer = 
        Get-ADComputer -Identity $ComputerName -Properties Description, MemberOf
    $MembershipList = 
        (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $GroupList.DistinguishedName -DifferenceObject $ADComputer.MemberOf -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent).InputObject
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name          = $ComputerName
        Description   = $ADComputer.Description
        G_SCCM_Member = if ($MembershipList) {$LookUpTable[$MembershipList].sAMAccountName -join ', ' } else {'n/a' }
    }
}
$Result | 
Export-Csv -Path 'Path.csv' -NoTypeInformation
$Result
```

This way you get the name, description and all groups with `G_SCCM` in their name the server is member of.

Comment: is it possible to remove "CN=,OU=,DC=" from the export ?

Comment: So you only want the `sAMAccountName` - not the `DistinguishedName`?

Comment: @RyomenS I updated my code suggestion. Try!